# Draw shapes using the Html5 Canvas api

Tags: javascript, canvas, vue.js

A while ago I decided to start working on a project that will keep me busy for a while and will help me sharpen my programming skills.
I do not underestimate the work behind apps like adobe xd, sketch.app, or figma but I just want to understand how those apps work and if I can do something similar.

The features of an app like this would allow me to experiment with a wide range of techniques, each one helping me in my journey to become a better programmer.

Here is a link to my little app: [draw](https://github.com/irosgrim/draw)

I picked Vue/vuex for state management but apart from that there is nothing Vue specific in it.
Most of the relevant code is in: `src/components/canvas`.

The downside of working on your own project is that you do not get any guidance from more experienced developers and this is the reason why I'm here on codereview.

Before I write even more code and losing control of whatever I'm doing, I would like to ask you to take a look at my code, review it, make suggestion and guide me if possible.

For example, this is the `Shape` class that allows me to draw some shapes on the canvas:

```js
import { degreesToRadians, mouseIsInsideEllipse, mouseIsInsideRectangle } from '@/helpers/geometry';
import { PolarCoordinate, Shadow, ShapeCoords, ShapeName, Stroke } from '@/Types/types';
import { uid } from 'uid';
import { RadiusHandle, ResizeHandle } from './handles';

export class Shape {
    public id = '';
    public x = 0;
    public y = 0;
    public endX = 0;
    public endY = 0;
    public width = 0;
    public height = 0;
    public stroke: Stroke | null = null;
    public fill = '';
    public type: ShapeName | '' = '';
    public rotation = 0;
    public radius: number[] | null = null;
    public shadow: Shadow | null = null;
    private _isMoving = false;
    private _isSelected = false;
    public radiusHandles: RadiusHandle[] | null =  null;
    public resizeHandles: ResizeHandle[] = [];
    
    constructor(type: ShapeName, shapeProperties: {coords?: ShapeCoords, stroke?: Stroke, fill?: string}, copyShape?: {x: number, y: number, h: number, w: number}) {
        this.id = uid(12);

        if(type === 'RECTANGLE') {
            this.radius = [0, 0, 0, 0];
        }

        if(shapeProperties.coords) {
            if(type === 'LINE') {
                this.x = shapeProperties.coords.start.x;
                this.y = shapeProperties.coords.start.y;
                this.endX = shapeProperties.coords.end.x;
                this.endY = shapeProperties.coords.end.y;
            } else {
                const isNegativeWidth = shapeProperties.coords.end.x <= shapeProperties.coords.start.x;
                const isNegativeHeight = shapeProperties.coords.end.y <= shapeProperties.coords.start.y;

                if(isNegativeWidth) {
                    this.x = shapeProperties.coords.end.x;
                    this.width = Math.abs(shapeProperties.coords.start.x - shapeProperties.coords.end.x);
                } else {
                    this.x = shapeProperties.coords.start.x;
                    this.width = Math.abs(shapeProperties.coords.end.x - shapeProperties.coords.start.x);
                }

                if(isNegativeHeight) {
                    this.y = shapeProperties.coords.end.y;
                    this.height = Math.abs(shapeProperties.coords.start.y - shapeProperties.coords.end.y);
                } else {
                    this.y = shapeProperties.coords.start.y;
                    this.height = Math.abs(shapeProperties.coords.end.y - shapeProperties.coords.start.y);
                }
            }
        }
        if(copyShape) {
            this.x = copyShape.x;
            this.y = copyShape.y;
            this.width = copyShape.w;
            this.height = copyShape.h;
        }

        this.stroke = shapeProperties.stroke ? shapeProperties.stroke : null;
        this.fill = shapeProperties.fill ? shapeProperties.fill : '';
        this.type = type;
    }

    private roundedRectangle(ctx: CanvasRenderingContext2D, x: number, y: number, width: number, height: number, radius: number[]) {
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(x + radius[0], y);
        ctx.lineTo(x + width - radius[1], y);
        ctx.quadraticCurveTo(x + width, y, x + width, y + radius[1]);
        ctx.lineTo(x + width, y + height - radius[2]);
        ctx.quadraticCurveTo(x + width, y + height, x + width - radius[2], y + height);
        ctx.lineTo(x + radius[3], y + height);
        ctx.quadraticCurveTo(x, y + height, x, y + height - radius[3]);
        ctx.lineTo(x, y + radius[0]);
        ctx.quadraticCurveTo(x, y, x + radius[0], y);
        ctx.closePath();
    }

    private applyShadow(ctx: CanvasRenderingContext2D) {
        ctx.shadowColor = this.shadow!.color;
        ctx.shadowBlur = this.shadow!.blur;
        ctx.shadowOffsetX = this.shadow!.x;
        ctx.shadowOffsetY = this.shadow!.y;
    }

    private drawLineResizeHandles(ctx: CanvasRenderingContext2D) {
        ctx.setLineDash([]);
        new ResizeHandle('W', {x: this.x, y: this.y}, Math.abs(this.endX - this.x), Math.abs(this.endY - this.y), ctx);
        // new ResizeHandle('E', {x: this.endX, y: this.endY}, Math.abs(this.endX - this.x), Math.abs(this.endY - this.y), ctx);
    }

    private drawResizeHandles(ctx: CanvasRenderingContext2D) {
        ctx.setLineDash([]);
        ctx.lineWidth = 1;
        ctx.strokeStyle = '#00a7f9';
        ctx.strokeRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);

        const handleCoordinate = ["NW", "NE", "SW", "SE", "N", "S", "W", "E"] as PolarCoordinate[];
        this.resizeHandles = [];

        handleCoordinate.forEach(polarPosition=> {
            this.resizeHandles = [...this.resizeHandles, new ResizeHandle(polarPosition, {x: this.x, y: this.y}, this.width, this.height, ctx)];
        });

        const text = `${this.width} x ${this.height}`;
        const infoBoxH = 16;
        const textWidth = ctx.measureText(text).width;
        const infoBoxW = textWidth + 16;

        ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(0, 166, 249, 0.7)';
        ctx.fillRect(this.x + this.width / 2 - infoBoxW / 2, this.y + this.height + 16 - infoBoxH / 2, infoBoxW, infoBoxH);
        ctx.fillStyle = "#ffffff";
        ctx.textAlign = "center";
        ctx.font = "12px Arial";
        ctx.fillText(text, this.x + this.width / 2, this.y + this.height + 16 + infoBoxH / 3.6);
    }

    private drawRadiusHandles(ctx: CanvasRenderingContext2D) {
        const handleCoordinate = ["NW", "NE", "SW", "SE"] as PolarCoordinate[];
        if(this.type === 'RECTANGLE' && this.width >= 50 && this.height >= 50) {
            this.radiusHandles = [];
            handleCoordinate.forEach((polarPosition, index) => {
                this.radiusHandles = [...this.radiusHandles!, new RadiusHandle(polarPosition, {x: this.x, y: this.y}, this.width, this.height, ctx, this.radius![index])]
            });
        }
    }

    public mouseIsOver(e: MouseEvent, offsetX: number, offsetY: number) {
        const mouseX = e.clientX - offsetX;
        const mouseY = e.clientY - offsetY;

        if(this.type === 'CIRCLE') {
            return mouseIsInsideEllipse(mouseX, mouseY, offsetX, offsetY, this.x, this.y, this.height, this.width);
        }

        if(this.type === 'RECTANGLE') {
            return mouseIsInsideRectangle(mouseX, mouseY, offsetX, offsetY, this.x, this.y, this.height, this.width);
        }

        if(this.type === 'LINE') { 
          
            return (
                mouseX < this.endX && mouseX > this.x &&
                mouseY > this.y - 5 && mouseY < this.endY + 5
            )
        }
    }

    public get isSelected(): boolean {
        return this._isSelected;
    }

    public set isSelected(value: boolean) {
        this._isSelected = value;
    }

    public get isMoving(): boolean {
        return this._isMoving;
    }

    public set isMoving(value: boolean) {
        this._isMoving = value;
    }

    public drawShape(ctx: CanvasRenderingContext2D) {
        ctx.save();
        const horisontalCenter = this.x + ( this.width / 2);
        const verticalCenter = this.y + (this.height / 2);

        ctx.translate(horisontalCenter, verticalCenter);
        ctx.rotate(degreesToRadians(this.rotation));
        ctx.translate(- horisontalCenter, - verticalCenter);

        if(this.shadow) {
            this.applyShadow(ctx);
        }

        if(this.radius) {
            const radiuses = this.radius.map( x => this.height/2 > x && this.width/2 > x);
            radiuses?.forEach( (r, i) => {
                if(!r) {
                    this.radius![i] = (this.height / 2);
                }
            })
        }

        switch(this.type) {
            case 'RECTANGLE':
                this.drawRectangle(ctx);
                break;
            case 'CIRCLE':
                this.drawCircle(ctx)
                break;
            case 'LINE':
                this.drawLine(ctx)
                break;
        }
    }

    public drawCircle(ctx: CanvasRenderingContext2D) {
        ctx.beginPath();

        if(this.fill) {
            ctx.fillStyle = this.fill;
            ctx.ellipse(this.x + this.width/2, this.y + this.height/2, this.width/2, this.height/2, 0, 0, 2*Math.PI);
            ctx.fill();
        }

        if(this.stroke) {
            ctx.setLineDash([]);
            ctx.strokeStyle = this.stroke.style;
            ctx.lineWidth = this.stroke.width;
            ctx.ellipse(this.x + this.width/2, this.y + this.height/2, this.width/2, this.height/2, 0, 0, 2*Math.PI);
            ctx.stroke();
        }

        ctx.restore();

        if(this.isSelected) {
            this.drawResizeHandles(ctx);
        }
        ctx.closePath();
    }

    public drawRectangle(ctx: CanvasRenderingContext2D) {
        if(this.fill) {
            ctx.fillStyle = this.fill;
            this.roundedRectangle(ctx, this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height, this.radius || [0,0,0,0]);
            ctx.fill();
        }

        if(this.fill && !this.radius) {
            ctx.fillStyle = this.fill;
            ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
        }
        
        if(this.stroke) {
            ctx.setLineDash([]);
            ctx.strokeStyle = this.stroke.style;
            ctx.lineWidth = this.stroke.width;
            this.roundedRectangle(ctx, this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height, this.radius || [0,0,0,0]);
            ctx.stroke();
        }

        ctx.restore();

        if(this.isSelected) {
            this.drawResizeHandles(ctx);
            this.drawRadiusHandles(ctx);
        }
    }

    public drawLine(ctx: CanvasRenderingContext2D) {
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.setLineDash([]);
        ctx.strokeStyle = 'black';
        ctx.moveTo(this.x, this.y);
        ctx.lineTo(this.endX, this.endY);
        ctx.stroke()
        ctx.closePath();
        ctx.restore();

        if(this.isSelected) {
            this.drawLineResizeHandles(ctx);
        }
    }

    public mouseIsOverRadiusHandle(mouseX: number, mouseY: number) {
        if(this.type === 'RECTANGLE') {
            return this.radiusHandles?.find(x => x.mouseIsOver(mouseX, mouseY))?.position || null;
        }
    }

    public mouseIsOverResizeHandle(mouseX: number, mouseY: number) {
        return this.resizeHandles.find(x => x.mouseIsOver(mouseX, mouseY))?.position || null;
    }

}
```

What could I improve and how should I structure it?

How would you approach adding features and focusing on each one?

What am I doing wrong and what would be a better alternative?

Is the performance of my app ok, or there are ways to improve it?

Are there alternative techniques for resizing shapes and detecting mouse over?

Here is a working example of the code from the repository above: [the drawing app](https://irosgrim.github.io/draw/)

Answer (score 2):

This is perfect example for inheritance. You should separate code into multiple files and get rid of

```
if(type === '...') {
  // ...
}
```

conditions. Shape class should contain only common functions like

```
public get isSelected(): boolean {}
public set isSelected(value: boolean) {}
public get isMoving(): boolean {}
public set isMoving(value: boolean) {}
// ...
```

Every shape then has own file. For example:

```
class Rectangle extends Shape {
  draw() {}
  isMouseOver() {}
  // ...
}
```

Everything else is pretty standard and ok.